# Reading data from firebase in swift but not being able to display it. Possibly variable scope error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

`

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
class mapVC: UIViewController {
    var name:String = ""
    var number:String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);
    var dict = fetchData()
    print(dict)

}
func fetchData()->[String:String]{
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    var uid:String=""
    var email:String=""
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if let user = user {
        let uid_local = user.uid
        let email_local = user.email
        uid=uid_local
        email=email_local!
    }
    ref.child("Users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.name = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
        print(value?["name"] as? String ?? "")
        self.number = value?["number"] as? String ?? ""
        print(value?["number"] as? String ?? "")
    })
    return(["Name":name,"Number":number,"Email":email,"UID":uid]);
}
}
```

Reading data from firebase in Swift but not being able to display it. Possibly variable scope error. The output of print(value?["name"] as? String ?? "" is the expected result) but is not being assigned to the self.name variable. I believe this is a scope error but I don't know for sure yet. All and any help is greatly appreciated since I am comparitively new to iOS and Swift.

Answer (score 2):

Because receiving data from Firebase is asynchronous task, you can't do it like this. You have to use completion handler for this.

First add completion handler as parameter of a function, also you don't need return type

```
func fetchData(_ completion: @escaping ([String:String]) -> ())
```

Then call completion when you receive your data

```
ref.child("Users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    ...
    completion(["Name":name,"Number":number,"Email":email,"UID":uid])
})
```

now you have access to data from Firebase in closure of `fetchData` function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    fetchData { dict in
        print(dict)
    }
}
```

**Note:** you won't have these data until receiving data from Firebase isn't done, so it takes some time

Comment: do you mean something like this - https://wordpress.com/page/praeco.net/118